# textview color does not change

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

the color does not change when the text color is light (for example, it turns black or off green when it is made white)

But there is no problem when I choose closed colors

what do you think is the reason

I used #ffffff white code like in the picture, but can you see the color?

[image]

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="random"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"/>
```

Comment: android:textColor="#ffffff"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use android:textColor property to set that like below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="random"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: i don't think OP is asking about _text_ color, i believe they are asking about shadows

Comment: Phew @a_local_nobody thought i misread, OP glad that was helpful